# Custom response in swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-apicontroller

I am writing

```
/// <summary>
/// someMethod
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">name</param>
/// <response code="200" cref="APIResult">Success</response>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet("someMethod")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(APIResult), 200)]
public APIResult someMethod(string name)
{
    return new APIResult();
}
```

But I can't get **APIResult** struct in swagger

[image]

What I have to do?

I use .net core 2.1
Library NSwag.AspNetCore Version=12.3.1

Comment: Can you post the full code and your Swagger configuration? What library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: @Helen,  fixed main post

Answer (score 1):

Because is by Annotations, not by comment:

```
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(APIResult), 200)]
 public async Task<APIResult> get()
 {
 }
```

swagger read the model what you want to expose

**UPDATE:** ok I'm sorry. I didn't read everything.

please try adding this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following, your return type is wrong

```
public async Task<ActionResult>
```

then

```
return Ok<object>;
```